# Empty output when calling a python script in C# project

Tags: python, c#, wpf, process

I would like to call a python script in my C# project , I'm using this function to do the job but unfortunately I didn't get any result and the result variable shows always an empty output. I would like to know what's the reason of this

```
    public string RunFromCmd(string rCodeFilePath, string args)
    {
        string file = rCodeFilePath;
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            var info = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonPath);
            info.Arguments = @"C:\Users\MyPc\ExternalScripts\HelloWorld.py" + " " + args;

            info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;

            using (var proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = info;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                if (proc.ExitCode == 0)
                {
                    result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("R Script failed: " + result, ex);
        }
    }
```

Click Event ( Calling funtion )

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pythonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHON_PATH");
            RunFromCmd(pythonPath, "");
        }
```

Python Script :

```
import sys

def main():
    text = "Hello World"
    return text


result = main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by setting `Copy if newer` instead of `Do Not Copy` to `HelloWorld.py` Script

[image]